Oracle SqlDeveloper column autocompletion without its table name
I use SQL developer version 23.1.1.345.
When I write a sql query, I would like to autocomplete the column name only. In case of a join, Sql Developer always give me the table_name.column_name even if there is no collision in the column_name.
To complete it, I wrote a sample :
create table FIRST_TABLE
(
    FIRST_F1 VARCHAR2 (10),
    FIRST_SECOND_F1 VARCHAR2 (10) --(foreign key SECOND_TABLE)
);

create table SECOND_TABLE
(
    SECOND_F1 VARCHAR2 (10)
);


When I write a join I have the following autocomplete choice :

I would like to have only the column name without the table name.

Expected: first_f1
Actual: first_table.first_f1

Is it a parameter to change this behavior ?
In Parameter -> Code Editor -> Completion Insight : I already unchecked the Generate Column/table alias automatically but without success.

"...even if there is no collision in the column_name..." -- You know that. The next developer won't, and she will waste hours debugging the query that otherwise would have been clear from the begining. Again, this is a bad idea.

This is an anti-pattern. It's a really bad idea to omit the table names in a query that includes multiple tables. If you prefer less typing, then you can alias the tables as in from first_table f, and then use f.mycolumn from then on.

@TheImpaler:  My question is about SqlDeveloper, used during the development. It's not the real request used by the application. Instead of downvote, try to propose some help.

select *
from first_table
join second_table on first_second_f1 = second_f1
where  

I know what you want, but this is the only reasonable solution -

If you don't include the table names, there's no way for the developer to know what the tool is recomending.
If you don't like, simply remove the table reference after the completion has helped you. Of course, you'll leave your code less maintainable, and more error prone. It's best to always include the actual object prefix when you're dealing with more than one object in your query.
